# How to get on hover the total number a path class matches an array value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

```js
var nationList = ["Austria", "France", "Austria", "Spain", "Italy", "United States", "France", "Congo", "Austria"];

var count = {};
nationList.sort();
nationList.forEach(function(i) {
  var i = i.replace(/^\s+/g, "");
  count[i] = (count[i] || 0) + 1;
});
console.log(count);
```

```html
<svg>
      <path class="Austria"></path>
      <path class="France"></path>
      <path class="Italy"></path>
      <path class="United States"></path>
      <path class="Spain"></path>
      <path class="Congo"></path>
    </svg>
```

I have an array:

```
var nationList = ["Austria", "France", "Austria", "Spain", "Italy", "United States", "France", "Congo", "Austria"];
```

I then run the following:

```
var  count = {};
nationList.sort();
nationList.forEach(function(i) { 
  var i = i.replace(/^\s+/g, "");
  count[i] = (count[i]||0) + 1;
});
console.log(count);
```

And it gives me:

```
Austria: 3
France: 2
Italy: 1
United States: 1
Congo: 1
Spain: 1
```

Now I have a series of `svg paths` with the country names as classes:

```
<svg>
  <path class="Austria"></path>
  <path class="France"></path>
  <path class="Italy"></path>
  <path class="United States"></path>
  <path class="Spain"></path>
  <path class="Congo"></path>
</svg>
```

If I `mousehover` `Austria` I should get `3` in console.

**NOTE**

I have path which are created as layers by [leaflet map](https://leafletjs.com/)

Comment: Could you explain why the down votes? I could update the question if have to

Comment: You don't want to use `class` for that, as e.g. that `United States` is parsed as two CSS classes, `States` and `United`.

Comment: Anyway, what's your question?

Comment: Your question seems slightly misleading.  It seems like you are asking about how to get the totals, but then by the end it seems your actual question is how to display them in an svg element

Comment: @Taplar no, I want to count how many times a path class matches an array value

Comment: @AKX I want to count how many times a path class matches an array value

Comment: @AKX and true about United States, I'll sort that our with an underscore later

Comment: why do you need svg and path instead of normal div?

Comment: @brk because I am using leaflet map

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing something, but you already have your `count` variable, so assuming the SVG is embedded in the page's markup and not an external file...

```
<path id="Austria" onmouseover="printCount(this)"></path>
```

...

```
var count = {};
nationList.sort();
nationList.forEach(function(i) { 
  var i = i.replace(/^\s+/g, "");
  count[i] = (count[i]||0) + 1;
});
console.log(count);

function printCount(path) {
    console.log(count[path.id.replace(/^\s+/g, "")]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, will test it now. So this will give me the relative total count of the current path?

Comment: Relative... to what?

Comment: path class austria = console count n. 3

Comment: that's using an id, I am using classes

Comment: Makes no particular difference. Use `path.className` if you are using classes (which you shouldn't, again).

Comment: I can't add the js inline with the path, tried using       `$("path").on("hover", function(){
        printCount(this);
      });` but not working, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why can't you add the JS inline?

Comment: because it's leaflet map loading the path

Comment: You forgot to mention that altogether in your initial question. Maybe reask the question with all relevant information included...

Comment: tried adding it via js as an attribute, which works, but says `(index):1 Uncaught ReferenceError: printCount is not defined
    at SVGPathElement.onmouseover`

Comment: Is `printCount` available in your window scope?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173903/discussion-between-rob-m-and-akx).

Comment: leaflet has a method for `mousehover`  so I do `layer.on({
        mouseover: printCount` but then when the function runs I get `undefined` which means it doesn't know `count[path.className]` but `count= {};` is available